# Ratio of the density between two markers

Tags: geometry

My friend gave me this 3D math problem to solve, and I have absolutely no idea on how to solve it! I don't even know where to start. I don't think I have the mental capacity to solve, nor the experience! =P

Secretly, I don't think it's possible, but you never know with fancy math problems like these.

Imagine an arbitrary function $f(x,y)$ in 3D space. Now, go along the surface and place markers in a grid-like fashion.

- If the markers were infinitely close, write a general formula for the ratio of the density of these markers given $2$ points (think like how derivatives generalized slope to a single point)
- Then find the formula for a unit sphere centered at the origin with the first point at the origin. Write it as a function $g(x, y)$

Anything helps! I haven't learned 3D geometry yet, so I am really lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The formula for the ratio at point $(x_1, y_1)$ compared to $(x_2, y_2)$ should be ${\sqrt{\frac{1+||\nabla{f(x_2, y_2)||^2}}{1+||\nabla{f(x_1, y_1)||^2}}}}$, where $\nabla$ is the gradient operator.
2. $g(x, y) = 1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. This only give the formula for the top half of the sphere, but if we include the bottom half, $g$ is no longer a function. Since the gradient at the origin is the zero vector, the formula for the ratio of any point $(x, y)$ compared to the origin is just ${\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-x^2-y^2}}}}$.

Explanation:

Locally, a 3-D function behave like the plane tangent to its surface. This is fortunate, because planes are easy to deal with. The slope of this plane is given by the magnitude of the gradient of the function. This means that we can find the ratio of the "shadow" of an infinitesimal area and the infinitesimal area simply by finding the area under a given area of the plane described above. As I interpreted the problem, this is the value that your friend is looking for after we divided that value by the value at a second point. Planes are extremely useful here, as the ratio of the shadow and the area on the plane does not change depending on the shape or size of the area we take. We can use trig to find a formula for the area of the shadow compared to a given unit area on the plane. If we do that for two points and divide the results, we get the formula above. 
For the second part, the formula for the unit hemisphere is pretty standard repertoire (or you can derive it from $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$). The gradient at the origin is 0, so the numerator of our formula (at point $(x_2, y_2)$) is 1. We can take the gradient of $g$ explicitly, giving us the substitution for the denominator.